# Oracle Wallet Connection setup for SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis

How to configure SSIS package to connect to oracle using oracle wallet? Specifically for using OLEDB to connect to oracle and load data to oracle tables.

Answer (score 0):

When using OLEDB, I believe you should choose the Integrated Security option which would have your connection string look like this:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyOracleDB;OSAuthent=1;
```

Since you're using wallet, you have no username and passwords.

This is assuming your wallet is configured properly in the first place, meaning test with sqlplus is positive.

I hope this helps.